# write a XML document from within a c# application?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, iis

I have a C# program that gathers system information.  All of it is complete execept writing to the xml file. I have passed `System version, IE version and Regedit` version into "ints" and "strings". Now the problem I am having is writing the output to two files:

1. `Sys_info.xml` - System info generated by the program
2. `unattend.xml` - For IIS setup, which uses the variables from the program

The IIS unattended.xml is found here:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/133/using-unattended-setup-to-install-iis/

The sad thing is I am not a programmer and the guy who wrote this is on a vacation

Anyhow here is the xml code for the unattended.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend"
xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State">
<servicing>
<!-- Install a selectable update in a package that is in the Windows Foundation     namespace -->
<package action="configure">
  <assemblyIdentity
     name="Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package"
     version="6.0.5308.6" ***reg version int from registry goes here(from my program)***
     language="neutral"
     processorArchitecture="x86" **** Processor architecture goes here(from my program)****
     publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
     versionScope="nonSxS"
  />
<selection name="IIS-WebServerRole" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-WebServer" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-CommonHttpFeatures" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-StaticContent" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-DefaultDocument" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-DirectoryBrowsing" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-HttpErrors" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-HttpRedirect" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-ApplicationDevelopment" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-ASPNET" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-NetFxExtensibility" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-ASP" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-CGI" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-ISAPIExtensions" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-ISAPIFilter" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-ServerSideIncludes" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-HttpLogging" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-LoggingLibraries" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-RequestMonitor" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-HttpTracing" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-CustomLogging" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-ODBCLogging" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-Security" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-BasicAuthentication" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-WindowsAuthentication" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-DigestAuthentication" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-URLAuthorization" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-RequestFiltering" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-IPSecurity" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-Performance" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-HttpCompressionStatic" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-WebServerManagementTools" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-ManagementConsole" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-ManagementScriptingTools" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-ManagementService" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-Metabase" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-WMICompatibility" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-LegacyScripts" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-LegacySnapIn" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-FTPPublishingService" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-FTPServer" state="true"/>
<selection name="IIS-FTPManagement" state="true"/>
<selection name="WAS-WindowsActivationService" state="true"/>
<selection name="WAS-ProcessModel" state="true"/>
<selection name="WAS-NetFxEnvironment" state="true"/>
<selection name="WAS-ConfigurationAPI" state="true"/>
</package>
</servicing>
</unattend>
```

Comment: Hm. If you were a programmer, I'd refer you to Microsoft's [reference manual on `XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Can you give some easy references or an example.I really got to finish this.MSDN examples are way too hard to implement

Comment: @MrLister: That's just mean - using XDocument would be much simpler than XmlWriter.

Comment: @user1235546: To be honest, if you're not a programmer it's going to be very hard for you to learn C# enough to get you going in short order. Do you not have any developers around at all?

Comment: AS a matter of fact i do but they won't be in the office till monday.I have rudimentary knowledge of 'C' and i was hoping to improvise on it.BTW What exactly is XDocument.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the cheapest (get the job done) thing you can do.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<?xml version=\'1.0\' ?>");
sb.Append("<unattend xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend' xmlns:wcm='http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State'>");
sb.Append("<servicing>");
sb.Append("<package action='configure'>");
sb.Append("  <assemblyIdentity");
sb.Append("     name='Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package'");
sb.Append("     version='6.0.5308.6' ");
sb.Append("     language='neutral'");
sb.Append("     processorArchitecture='x86' ");
sb.Append("     publicKeyToken='31bf3856ad364e35'");
sb.Append("     versionScope='nonSxS'");
sb.Append("  />");

foreach(var kvp in dictionaryOfValues)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("<selection name='{0}' state='{1}'/>", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
sb.Append("</package>");
sb.Append("</servicing>");
sb.Append("</unattend>");

// Write the string to a file.
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.xml");
file.WriteLine(sb.ToString);

file.Close();
```

of course you can parse it into XmlReaders and XmlWriters but if you want the job done without having to learn much this code should get you out of trouble. It assumes you have a Dictionary of Key Values for the selection tags. if you don't then just add a line for each one and use append format to stick the right values in.

When the boys come in on Monday they'll clean it up for you :)